# (Non-ring) Wallet signatures

Tags: cryptography

I am reading about ECDSA and EdDSA. I was wondering what the Monero `void  crypto_ops::generate_signature` signature is based upon. From the code, I see that the math to generate one is

k = rand()
t3 = kB
buf = H(data) || pk || t3
c = Hs(buf)
r = k - c.sk

and the signature then is the tuple (c,r). This seems to take some ideas from [standard ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECDSA), but I would like to know what scheme exactly is used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `crypto_ops::generate_signature` function is using the [Schnorr signature scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature).